# Cross-platform high-level widget toolkits for C

Tags: c, user-interface, qt, widget, gtk

Are there any high-level, cross-platform, and abstracted (simple to use) widget toolkits for C that are either very lightweight and fast or can be compiled for other toolkits, such as Qt and GTK+?

EDIT:
Most C++ libraries lack C bindings, so they will be of little (or no) help.

Comment: gtk itself is cross-platform and written in C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enlightenment enables real cross platform from Windows CE to WIndows 7, from Linux to embedded Linux,  Mac OS to Mac OS X and it *is* leightwieght

[www.enlightenment.org](http://www.enlightenment.org)

Comment: hmm.. I never used it, though it seems there are no C bidnings :/ though maybe there are no bindings needed for C (as itself maybe writte in C) you should investigate on your onw on that...

Comment: Enlightenment Foundation Libraries are written in C, but I was looking for something more portable.

Comment: "More portable" in which way more portable? If you have further restictions just tell us, so we don't need to stab in the dark...

Comment: EFL hasn't been fully ported to the Win* platform. See http://trac.enlightenment.org/e/wiki/EFLWindowsVS .

Answer (score 2):

All GUI toolkits have their quirks and require some time to become familiar with.

If you mean pure C, then [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) is the most likely choice, any of the others I'm familiar with are written in C++, so C++ is their native language binding. I have written a simple application with GTK+ in C, and once you become accustom to the [container](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/LayoutContainers.html) methodology for layout control it becomes quite reasonable to use. It is licensed under [GNU LGPL 2.1](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.html).

One additional factor that can influence choice are licensing requirements, typically whether your usage is open-source of a particular license or a proprietary application.

[wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) uses a [LGPL-like](http://www.wxwidgets.org/about/newlicen.htm) license to allow open source and proprietary usage.

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products) is available under [various licenses](http://qt.nokia.com/products/licensing), GPL, LGPL, and a non-free (gratis) commercial license, and is natively C++ binding.

Comment: It's likely that I'd be dynamically linking, so licensing requirements weren't a big concern of mine. I was looking for something more lightweight than any of the three listed.

Comment: Can you be more specific in defining "lightweight" or "high-level"? Do you want a cross-platform GUI toolkit or a drawing library (I'm thinking of Cario, http://www.cairographics.org/ ). Cross-platform is basically never lightweight, as the portability costs. E.g. Java.

Answer (score 0):

My choice is FLTK (http://www.fltk.org) but neither it nor the aforementioned wxWidgets are for C.  They're C++ libraries.